# scroll magic Pin() creating gap

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, parallax, scrollmagic

I'm trying to have a parallax effect on my website using ScrollMagic (like this example: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html )

my HTML code structure is like:

```
<main>
  <section class="header"></section>
  <section class="content">
      <section class="section1">...</section>
      <section class="section2">...</section>
      <section class="section3">...</section>
      <section class="section4">...</section>
  </section>
</main>
```

and javascript:

```
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: ".header" ,
  duration: "200%",
  triggerHook: 0,
})
  .setTween(timeline)
  .setPin("main")
  .addTo(controller);
```

but there is a gap at the end of `section3` and the image from `.header` is showing through.
I tried using `pushFollowers: false` but then the gap appears between every `section` through my margins

it's my first time using ScrollMagic so I'm sure there is a solution I'm not aware of, will appreciate  your help